# スマートフォン用Web版Gmailにて、IMAPを有効化する方法はありますか？

Tags: gmail

Gmailのスマートフォン用のWebのUIは以下のような画面になっています。
ここからIMAPを有効化したいのですが、できません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

PC版にアクセスすればIMAP設定を行うことが可能ですが、PCを持っていない方にIMAP設定を有効化してもらうために、スマートフォン/Web上でIMAP設定を可能にする方法を探しています。

なお、2024/1でGmailの簡易HTML画面が廃止されるため、簡易HTML画面を利用しない方法でIMAP設定を行う方法を知っている方がいれば、ぜひ教えてください。

Comment: スマートフォン用のブラウザには、だいたい「PC版サイト」の用な項目で、PC版ブラウザのように振る舞う設定が有ります。それを使うというのは選択肢に有りますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
現在のGmailの場合、一度でもスマートフォン用WebUIを開いてしまうと、「PC版サイト」のような設定を行なってもPC版表示ができない状況で、困っております。

Comment: なるほど。つまり、選択肢には有るということですね。
「一度でもスマートフォン用WebUIを開いてしまうと」駄目ということは無くて、
PC版モードでGmailのトップですとか、PC版のURLに遷移すれば大丈夫なはずです。
後はこれをどのような手順にまとめて、どのように説明するかですね。
これは相手のリテラシー次第で変わりそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
先に別のタブで何かしらのページを開き、PC版サイト表示に設定した状態で、PC版Gmailトップへのリンクを踏むことでモバイル版にてPC/WebUIのgmailを開くことに成功しました。
助かりました